# Parsing Json Data in html tag

Tags: php, regex, json

I need to extract a json object inside a web page's script. This is a part of the web page:

```
<html>
<script>
    .....
</script>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(function(){



        $(\"#map5\").gMap({ maptype: G_SATELLITE_MAP,
        controls: false,
                  scrollwheel: false,

                  markers: [

{.....},{......},],

latitude: 24.70115790054175,
longitude: 46.04358434677124,
zoom: 5
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the the JSON object that starts wit `{ maptype:`. I thought of using `regular expression` approach to achieve this. Here is what I did:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$regex_pattern = "/\<script.*/";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$html,$matches);
```

However, my pattern seems to select the first line of the object only! I couldn't figure out a way to make it select all the object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: regexes by default only consider individual lines of text. you need the multi-line `/m` flag

Comment: FYI, that's not JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elsalamoe 3aleikom :D

Here's how you do it:

```
$script = <<<FIL
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(function(){



        $(\"#map5\").gMap({ maptype: G_SATELLITE_MAP,
        controls: false,
                  scrollwheel: false,

                  markers: [

{.....},{......},],

latitude: 24.70115790054175,
longitude: 46.04358434677124,
zoom: 5
});

});
</script>
FIL;

preg_match_all('/<script[^>]*>.*?\.gMap\(\s*({.*?})\);.*?<\/script>/mis', $script, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

[Online demo with explanation](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1sA5).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your pattern fail is that the dot `.` don't match newlines, if you want it does, you must add the `s` modifier at the end of your pattern. The multiline mode (m modifier) is not useful here.

Try this:

```
$json = (preg_match('~\.gMap\s*+\(\s*+\K\{.+?\}(?=\s*+\)\s*+;)~s', $html, $result))?
    $result[0] : false;
```